# rename multiple images before upload

Tags: php, file-upload, phpmyadmin

I wish to upload multiple images on the server, however before saving it on the server i want that the name of the files that are being uploaded should change into 1,2,3,4.. and so on  depending on the number of images uploaded and then it should save the file on server.

Currently the part of my code that deals with renaming is

```
$target = "$upload_dir/$_SESSION[myusername]Rejoin.$file[name]";
```

Would appreciate if someone could tell me the correct code to do so

Comment: You need to store image name in database and fetch last row from image table when uploaded new images and there get last image name and split by . (dot) so you get 1,2,3,4,5 i mean last image name and increment those variable by one and store in database

Answer (score 0):

You could change name in for/foreach loop -

```
$fdata = $_FILES['username'];
if(is_array($fdata['name']))
{
        $uploads_dir = '/uploads';
        for($i = 0; $i < count($fdata['name']); ++$i)
        {
            $name_of_file = $_FILES['username']['name'][$i]; //[$count];
            $temp_name = $_FILES['username']['tmp_name'][$i]; //[$count];
            move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "$uploads_dir/"."$name_of_file");
        }
}
```

Comment: pls change username to your filename